Is the bootloader correctly jumping to the application?
I’m using Keil5 and STM32F103ZET6. I’m writing a bootloader that will be placed at the flash base address 0x0800 0000. After some operations, it will jump to the correct application address at 0x0800 4000.
In my bootloader code, I jump as follows:
#define apdr 0x0800 4001
void (*app)(void);
app = ((void (*)(void))apdr);
app();

The disassembled code looks like this:
RESET
__Vectors
    0x08004000:    20002400    .$.     DCD    536880128
    0x08004004:    08004145    EA..    DCD    134234437
    0x08004008:    08004151    QA..    DCD    134234449

Reset_Handler
    0x08004144:    f8dfd01c    ....    LDR      sp,[pc,#28] ; [0x8004164] = 0x20002400
    0x08004148:    4807        .H      LDR      r0,[pc,#28] ; [0x8004168] = 0x8004195
    0x0800414a:    4780        .G      BLX      r0
    0x0800414c:    4807        .H      LDR      r0,[pc,#28] ; [0x800416c] = 0x8004131
    0x0800414e:    4700        .G      BX       r0


Theoretically, I should fetch the reset vector from address 0x0800 0004 and then jump to execute it. However, I’ve noticed that as long as I set apdr to any odd address between 0x0800 4001 and 0x0800 414D, the application still runs. Why is that?
One more question: I added the ldr sp, =__initial_sp instruction in my reset_handler. When I look at the disassembled code, I see that the compiler translated this into a 32-bit instruction. Will this work correctly in Thumb mode?

Yes, I'm aware of this issue, but the main point is not this. The focus is that when I set the APDR to a range from the starting address 0x0800 4000 to the memory address at the end of the reset_handler, 0x0800 414D, the main function in the application still executes. I have no idea how they are being executed. Additionally, due to issues with the debugger, when the bootloader is present, the debugger cannot track the execution, and I am unable to inspect the specific values of the registers.
